# how to combine a do while loop and setInterval timer function

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am trying to simulate a dice roll by combining a do while loop and a setInterval function.

the goal is this: user clicks dice roll button. they view a series of numbers and then the roll stops and returns a value.

my idea was to use the 'do while' loop to control how many iterations occur before the dice stops ‘rolling’. i’ve tried a few different things but nothing has worked so far. my latest attempt is below.

```
function diceRoll(){
    theNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(theNum);
    console.log(counter);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    counter = 1;
    myVar = '';
    $('#start').click(function(){
        do {
        //
        myVar = setInterval(function(){ diceRoll() }, 500);
        } while (counter < 10)
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget the `do while` loop. You just need to keep track of 'state' so you can act accordingly at each interval. The `counter` will do fine in this simple case.

If using an interval you want to clear the interval when you have finished with it. It would also make sense to 'block' the start button while the dice in rolling.

Here is a modified example of your code which should achieve what you are trying to do:

```js
var vals = ["\u2680", "\u2681", "\u2682", "\u2683", "\u2684", "\u2685"];

function setValue(num) {
  $("div").text(vals[num - 1]);
}

var intervalId;
var counter = 1;

function diceRoll() {
  theNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  counter = counter + 1;
  setValue(theNum);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#start').click(function() {
    if (intervalId)
      return; // Don't allow click if already running.

    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
      if (counter < 10)
        diceRoll();
      else {
        // Reset state ready for next time.
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
        counter = 1;
      }
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="start">Click to Roll</a>

<div>

</div>
```

Comment: awesome, love the dice!,

Comment: all the answers were good, but i'll have to pick this one. i'll be using the dice font for this little game i'm building. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `do while`. You can just handle the indexing yourself. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4vr9cqcg/)

```
function diceRoll() {
  theNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  console.log(theNum);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter < 10) {
      diceRoll()
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` returns immediately, so all your code is doing is kicking off a very large number of iterations (the `counter` variable will not be incremented before many many versions are executing)

You should just recall the same function with `setTimeout` from within the function itself.

```js
var counter = 0;

function diceRoll(){
    theNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(theNum);
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter<10){
         setTimeout(diceRoll,500); 
    }
}

diceRoll()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems in your example,

The first problem is, setInterval will keep execute the given function after certain function, you don't need a do while loop for similar purpose.

The second problem is, instead of using setInterval to keep execute and check whether counter < 10 to clearInterval, you may use setTimeout instead, to create another timeout when counter < 10 and call the diceRoll function itself.

```
var counter, 
    timeout;

function diceRoll(){
    theNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1; 
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(theNum);
    console.log(counter);
    if (counter < 10) {
        timeout = setTimeout(diceRoll, 500);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#start').click(function(){
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
        }
        counter = 0;
        diceRoll();
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more on how does it fail?